# Mysterious mouse event closes jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is obviously a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

So we are tasked with writing the front-end of a missile launch control system. We opt for a Spartan layout given that this is deadly serious: just a text input box and a button to enter the code:

[image]

For safety purposes, upon clicking on the "OK" button we will display a dialog asking the user to confirm:

[image]

As a usability finishing touch we add a key listener for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button that will also result in clicking the "OK" button (using `$.trigger()`).

Unfortunately, the confirmation dialog is only displayed when the user clicks on the "OK" button but not when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. When we hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the dialog does not appear at all.

Worst still, after adding some debugging messages it appears that the dialog is indeed displayed for a fraction of a millisecond and then for some reason the "Yeap" button is clicked. So when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit, missile launch is immediately confirmed!

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q8po0y12/).

Code below:

```js
function inputKeyListener(evt) {
  console.log('key listener - triggered key code is: ' + evt.keyCode);
  if (evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('#missile-launch-button').click(); // Directly calling confirm() doesn't work either
  }
}

function missileLaunchButtonClickHandler(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  confirm();
}

function confirm() {
  var launchCode = $('#missile-launch-code-input').val();
  const dialog = $('#missile-launch-confirmation-modal');
  dialog.dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    open: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('confirm :: open is called');
    },
    close: function() {
      console.log('confirm :: close is called');
    },
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yeap": function() {
        console.log('Confirmation button was clicked');
        $(this).dialog("close");
        console.log('missile launch with code [' + launchCode + '] was confirmed!');
      },
      "Maybe not just yet": function(ev) {
        console.log('Abort button was clicked');
        $(this).dialog("close");
        console.log('Armageddon was averted');
      }
    }
  });

  dialog.dialog('open');
  console.log('by this time the dialog should be displayed');
}


$('#missile-launch-confirmation-modal').dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});


$('#missile-launch-button').click(missileLaunchButtonClickHandler);

$(document).on('keydown', inputKeyListener);
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id='missile-launch-confirmation-modal' title='Confirm missile launch' </div>
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span> Are you sure you want to unleash nuclear Armageddon?
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Enter missile launch code:</div>
    <div>
      <input id='missile-launch-code-input' type='text' autofocus/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id='missile-launch-button' type='button'>OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update

In the code above the `inputKeyListener` is bound to `keydown` on document. Binding it more narrowly to the `keydown` on the text input, as in:

```
$('#missile-launch-code-input').on('keydown', inputKeyListener);
```

… results in the exact same behavior.

## Update II

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011896/274677) suggests that `stopPropagation` is ineffective here because "*event bubbling isn't really in play here*" and explains that `preventDefault` should be used to "*[stop] the key event from reaching other page elements (i.e. that button)*". I am a bit confused with those two statements taken together. I thought that `stopPropagation` is *precisely* what one uses to stop a "*key event from reaching other page elements*". Moreover there are two further points of confusion.

The first point of confusion is that the confirmation dialog `div` is not a parent DOM element of the text input `div`, so it is unclear how a keyboard event at the text input `div` is intercepted by a *sibling* (not *parent*) DOM element. I think this is in fact the reason that `stopPropagation` is ineffective but still it's not clear to me why (regardless of `stopPropagation`) the event reaches the confirmation dialog button which lies in a sibling `div`.

The second point of confusion is that if we log the event we capture in the "Yeap" button function handler, e.g. like this:

```
buttons: {
       "Yeap": function(ev) {
       console.log(ev);
```

… what we in fact see in the console is:

[image]

… so it is a **mouse** event, not a keyboard event that confirms the dialog. Given that (in the scenario where one simple hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>) the only **mouse** event we are generating  is in the `inputKeyListener`:

```
$('#missile-launch-button').click();
```

… this means that it is this event that results in the confirmation of the dialog, not the keyboard event we get by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I just replaced `evt.stopPropagation();` with `evt.preventDefault();` and it works as expected.

Comment: @GauravBhor yeah, but why? `preventDefault()` is for preventing the "browsers default behavior". How come the "browser's default behavior" in this case be to send a mouse event to an unrelated `div` element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a case of jQuery UI being slightly too helpful for its own good: when a `dialog` opens, it puts the first button inside it into focus, just in time for the "enter" key event to trigger the button (which is the browser's default behavior when the user hits "enter" while a button is in focus.)

Using `preventDefault` in your `inputKeyListener` stops the key event from reaching other page elements (i.e. that button).  `stopPropagation` is harmless but will have no useful effect in either `inputKeyListener` or `missileLaunchButtonClickHandler` because event bubbling isn't really in play here.

Here's a demo with no preventDefault or stopPropagation, and a dummy button included to harmlessly catch the autofocus, just to confirm that this is what's happening:

```js
function inputKeyListener(evt) {
  console.log('key listener - triggered key code is: ' + evt.keyCode);
  if (evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
    // $('#missile-launch-button').click(); // Directly calling confirm() doesn't work either
    confirm(); // Does too!
  }
}

function missileLaunchButtonClickHandler(e) {
  confirm();
}

function confirm() {
  var launchCode = $('#missile-launch-code-input').val();
  const dialog = $('#missile-launch-confirmation-modal');
  dialog.dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    open: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('confirm :: open is called');
    },
    close: function() {
      console.log('confirm :: close is called');
    },
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Hmmmm": function() {
        console.log('First button inside the dialog was clicked.');
      },
      "Yeap": function() {
        console.log('Confirmation button was clicked');
        $(this).dialog("close");
        console.log('missile launch with code [' + launchCode + '] was confirmed!');
      },
      "Maybe not just yet": function(ev) {
        console.log('Abort button was clicked');
        $(this).dialog("close");
        console.log('Armageddon was averted');
      }
    }
  });

  dialog.dialog('open');
  console.log('by this time the dialog should be displayed');
}


$('#missile-launch-confirmation-modal').dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});


$('#missile-launch-button').click(missileLaunchButtonClickHandler);

$(document).on('keydown', inputKeyListener);
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id='missile-launch-confirmation-modal' title='Confirm missile launch' </div>
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span> Are you sure you want to unleash nuclear Armageddon?
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Enter missile launch code:</div>
    <div>
      <input id='missile-launch-code-input' type='text' autofocus/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id='missile-launch-button' type='button'>OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### on event.preventDefault vs event.stopPropagation

To expand on this, per "Update II":  `stopPropagation` prevents events bubbling up to parent DOM nodes.  Normally, for example, click events bubble upwards from the node directly clicked on through every parent node.

The reason `stopPropagation` is irrelevant here is because `dialog` is not a parent of the input element: event bubbling wouldn't have reached `dialog`.  So there's no reason to stop the event bubbling with `stopPropagation`, because it wouldn't have triggered anything meaningful anyway.

The events stopped by `event.preventDefault`, by contrast, have nothing to do with the DOM structure -- these events don't care if parent, sibling, grandchild, or third cousin twice removed; `event.preventDefault` simply means "whatever the default behavior of the browser would have been in this situation, don't do that."  So `event.preventDefault` on a form submit stops the form being submitted, for example.

In the case described in this question, the default browser behavior if the user hits the "enter" key while a button is  in focus is to trigger a click event (which is, yes, a mouse event) on that button, regardless of where the button is in the DOM.  So using `event.preventDefault` here prevents that default behavior, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to call the **missileLaunchButtonClickHandler** inside your **inputKeyListener** function.

After you need to add a "preventDefault" to your **missileLaunchButtonClickHandler** function because the dialog is closing automatically when you hit ENTER. The **preventDefault** avoid the dialog to close automatically.

Change your **missileLaunchButtonClickHandler** function to this:

```
function missileLaunchButtonClickHandler(e) {
   //e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   confirm();
 }
```

and modify your **inputKeyListener** to this:

```
function inputKeyListener (evt) {
       console.log('key listener - triggered key code is: '+evt.keyCode);
       if (evt.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
         evt.stopPropagation();
         missileLaunchButtonClickHandler(evt);
         $('#missile-launch-button').click(); // directly calling confirm() doesn't work either
       }
     }
```