# sweet alert immidiately closed before click OK button or hit enter when sweet alert appeared

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

im new using sweet alert, first i will show the code :

```
    $('#byr').keydown(function (e){
      var bayar = Number($('#byr').val());
      var total = Number($('.rp-harga').text());
      var kmb = $('.rp-kmb').text();

      if(e.keyCode == 13)
      {
        if(bayar<total)
        {
          alert("Uang Anda Kurang");
        }
        else {
          swal("Transaksi Berhasil", "Kembalian : Rp " + (bayar-total).toString(), "success");
        }
      }
    });
```

The problem is when i hit enter after fill the input text with else condition, it will show the sweet alert, but the sweet alert will immidiately closed before i click OK button or hit enter when sweet alert appear

I tried adding `e.preventDevaults()`, and get these problem :

1. if i add it before swal code, the alert cant appear in else contidion
2. if i add it after swal code, the same problem will happen (swal closed immidiately before click OK / hit enter).

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tudovbut/1/) is a working JSFiddle with my problem.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348785/javascript-sweetalert-popup-closes-itself-after-a-quick-second

Comment: the HTML code just like this   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="byr" >. I already see that post, but the question using button, and i have no idea on my work which it using input text

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault();` when you call `swal()`.

Comment: It's probably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010744/mysterious-mouse-event-closes-jquery-ui-dialog/44011896#44011896

Comment: i tried using it but still get the same problem

Comment: using `keyup` instead of `keydown` event worked for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using [sweetalert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2). This plugin has a configuration option:

> **allowEnterKey**: If set to false, the user can't confirm the modal by pressing the Enter or Space keys, unless they manually focus the confirm button.

Therefore you can:

- disable this feauture setting allowEnterKey to false
- call **swal** after 10 milliseconds in order to overcome the following src code for the first keydown:

  window.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;

```js
$('#byr').keydown(function (e) {
    var bayar = Number($('#byr').val());
    var total = 0;

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (bayar < total) {
            alert("Uang Anda Kurang");
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                swal({
                    title: "Transaksi Berhasil",
                    text: "Kembalian : Rp " + (bayar - total).toString(),
                    type: "success",
                    allowEnterKey: true // default value
                });
            }, 10)
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.2/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="byr">
```